# Can I bind a grid to a Kendo mvvm external editor?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui

So, in Kendo, you can bind inputs or spans to your data, for example:

```
    <input data-bind="value: selected.title" />

    <textarea rows='5' data-bind="value: selected.interestingNotes" required></textarea>
```

I have spans, inputs etc in an external editor, but I also need to display a editable grid in the editor, to permit editing of data in one of the columns, based on data in a nested json array in the same dataSource as the original grid.

Say that three times fast!

My question is: Can I bind my nested grid in the external editor to the array of data in the original grid? The array name is, for example 'approvers', so I thought it would look something like:

```
    <div id="Grid" data-role="grid" data-bind="source: selected.approvers">
```

I haven't been able to return anything.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need some javascript function to create a dataSource to do the trick, here is simple dataSource creator function

```
function createDs(datas) {
    return new kendo.data.DataSource({
      data: datas
    });
}
```

then your MVVM code should be like this

```
<div id="myGrid" data-role="grid" data-bind="source: createDs(selected.approvers)">
```